# How to Build the Github Portfolio

Tags: github

I am a web developer and I want to build my GitHub portfolio for my Clients and remote jobs.
Can anyone guide me on this?
I have experience in Reactjs, Vuejs and Python Django.
Should I contribute to exisitng open source projects or should I develop my own?

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because this question is blindly off topic

Comment: u need to create a github repo with [username].github.io and place all the code inside of it and its done

check this repo `https://github.com/muftisamiullah/muftisamiullah.github.io`
and check my portfolio `https://muftisamiullah.github.io/`

Comment: @Sumithran What do you mean by "off topic"?

Answer (score 1):

Contributing to open source projects might be difficult since you have to understand their code base, git workflow etc. Instead start with what you know and try to get up and running with 2 to 3 projects. You will get experience with committing code, responding to issues, working on pull requests etc. Then you can transition towards contributing to bigger open source projects.